# Discord embed message not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

My discord bot is sending the wrong embed message. Its a hug command, if someone doesn't mention somebody the bot sends an error message in the channel with the following content: **Please mention a valid user!** I want to send this message as a embed, but its not working correctly. Everytime i use the command without mentioning someone i don't get an error in my console. When i mention someone it works, but it sends the Error message as well. **Here's a screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgAmC.png

**My code**:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = require('../config.json');
const hugGif = require('./Huggifs.json');

module.exports = {
    name: "hug",
    description: "Posts a hug gif.",
    aliases: ['hug'],
    execute(client, message, args) {

        if (!message.mentions.users.first())
        return message.channel.send();
        const aembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTitle(`**Please mention a valid user!**`)
        message.channel.send(aembed);

    const gif = hugGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * hugGif.length)];
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('BLUE')
        .setTitle(`${message.author.username} hugs ${message.mentions.users.first().username}!`)
        .setImage(gif)
        .setFooter( `Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: `if (!message.mentions.users.first())
        return message.channel.send();` ??? This is not the recommended structure for an if statement. Also, please share the error you're getting if you expect to receive help. Why are you calling `.send()` empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```js
return message.channel.send();
```

There are two problems:

1. If there are no `mentions` in the message, you immediately call return. Anything below that `return` statement will not be executed
2. You are calling `.send()` empty

You sould create your embed first and then `return message.channel.send(<embed>)`.

Your `if statement` also looks strange, you should do it like this:

```
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.users.first();

if(!metionedMember) {
   // create you embed here
   return message.channel.send("your embed here");
}

// do things if there is a mention inside the message
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)